# How to read updated file from hdfs in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running spark stream and I am reading one file from hdfs location. Same file is updated by different service. Now I want to read the updated file in Spark Stream. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Should this file be the streaming source or static source (and even these can be updated).

Comment: This file in hdfs is a json file which is updated daily by some service and we want to read the updated file in spark structured streaming

Comment: As the streaming source or as a file to, say,  join agaist, i.e. static source?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
streamingContext.fileStream[KeyClass, ValueClass, InputFormatClass](dataDirectory)
// or
streamingContext.textFileStream(dataDirectory) // for text file
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Can we do it in intervals? Our case use is hdfs file is updated at intervals and we want to update the file without shutting the stream,